# Does Storm DRPCTopology have a inbuilt queue?

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to setup a storm topology to get updates from social networks, process them and write to a backend. I thought about getting the data and using a kafka queue and let kafka spout read from the queue. But on reading about DRPCTopology, it looks like I just need to send data to DRPC server and it handles forwarding to spouts. Does the DRPC server have a queue inbuilt? So for my use case can I use that instead of kafka spout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: Does the DRPC server have a queue inbuilt?

Yes, the [drpc server](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/clj/backtype/storm/daemon/drpc.clj) that comes with storm uses an internal `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

> Q: So for my use case can I use that instead of kafka spout?

Only if you expect relatively low volume, as the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` will consume memory with no way to fall to disk like Kafka does.